# How to write modular code in netbeans java swing applications?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, modular

I am creating my java Swing application in Netbeans. At present there are more than 2000 lines of code. Is it right to have these many number of lines in a single file. Moreover the IDE has become slow when i am editing this file. Is there any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In larger swing projects I do partinioning of the app like that:

- Have one class per GUI element like JPanel,JDialog etc.
- Use a separate package for each screen, especially if you have to implement customized TableModels or other complex data structures
- Don't use anonymous and inner classes, implement instead an ActionListener and check ActionEvent.getActionCommand() in there.

Comment: is there any way to configure netbeans so that it does all this modifications you mentioned to my existing project?

Comment: @rgksugan AFAIK there is not such an option, you should use standard refactoring, 2K lines is not huge this could be done manually in a few hours